# Migrate to academia.SE

Tags: feature-request, migration

Recently [a question was asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675265/postdoctoral-fellowship-what-is-it-about) that I think would be much better on academia.SE. The question isn't about math at all -- the exact same question without changing any word could have been asked about philosophy or geology postdocs. It's true that the question being about math postdocs in particular could change the answers a bit, but it's IMO better to specify that on a question posted on academia.SE rather than post here.

I'm not here to bash the OP, it's just an example: it's not unreasonable, IMO, to believe that this situation can happen again (a question posted on math.SE that is really about academia). So here you go:

> Is it possible to enable migrating of questions from math.SE to academia.SE?

---

In February, academia.SE was still a beta site so enabling migration wasn't possible. Since then, it graduated, but math.SE stills receives some academia-focused questions from time to time. Has the situation changed?

Answer (score 10):

User-driven migration will not be enabled until Academia.SE graduates. It's a SE policy to not enable user-driven migration to beta sites.

But moderators can migrate questions anywhere on the SE network. The tricky part is bringing the question to their attention. It is natural to flag for moderator's attention simultaneously with voting to close as off-topic. Unfortunately (to my understanding) the flags are cleared automatically when the question gets closed, so it's possible for moderators to miss them. A more reliable way is to flag *after* the question is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Before opening user-driven migration channel, SE needs to know that users understand what should be migrated. Strong record of flag-moderator migration would help demonstrate that.

In the past $90$ days, only $1$ question was migrated to Academia. And it was rejected. Migration channel is not ready for prime-time, I'm afraid.

If a question appears to be off-topic for "should be on Academia" reason, I suggest voting to close with a custom off-topic reason "... should have been asked on Academia.SE". This has  a side benefit to the author: they can read up on the standards of Academia.SE before stating their question there.

Comment: This statistic doesn't take into account the questions that are asked here, closed/unanswered and then reasked on academia, though. I've seen it happen at least twice in the past month.

Comment: [...And a new question was migrated!](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/31747/should-i-mention-in-statement-of-purpose-that-my-undergrad-degree-is-in-a-differ)